# Is fmap applying strictly in IO?

Tags: haskell, io, lazy-evaluation

In the Parallel & Concurrent Haskell book, at http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch09.html#sec_timeout , why `fmap Just m` doesn't just instantly return a thunk (defeating the purpose of the time limit)?

Or for `IO` something is special and `fmap` always forces a result? That would surprise me, as the `monad-par` package uses `NFData` and forcing to avoid that kind of behaviour AFAIK.

I surely miss something. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this answer, I'm using the word 'computation' to describe the effectful, interacting with the environment, part of executing an IO action. Terminology varies.

Given an IO computation `act :: IO a` the computation `fmap Just act` is a computation which (when run) runs the whole of computation `act` and then applies Just to the result.

It doesn't instantly return a thunk. To do that it would have to defer the computation `act` into the thunk, and computations can't be put into thunks, only evaluations. Thunks contain pure evaluations only and that's precisely why they work - we know it's OK to defer the evaluation, because we know that it doesn't matter when the evaluation is performed, the answer will still the be same. That's not true of the execution of computations, which can interact with the outside world and may return different answers depending on the environment when it is run.

The primitives (arguably "language-breaking" primitives) `unsafePerformIO` and `unsafeInterleaveIO` allow you to break the rules in the preceding paragraph and bury an IO computation into a thunk, which is occasionally what you really want and often a terrible, terrible idea.

Comment: I guess lazy IO piggybacks on the `unsafe`s then?

Comment: Yes it does, and it lives up to the 'unsafe'. Most of the lazy IO stuff is implemented with `unsafeInterleaveIO`.

Comment: Here is a very old rant by Oleg on that subject: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-March/023073.html

Comment: So `fmap f act` is computed up the part actually performing `IO`, but the pure part added by `f` might still need to be evaluated.

Comment: precisely. Does the definition `fmap f act = do a <- act; return (f a)` make that more obvious?